# Problema al acortar multiples URLs con TinyURL

Tags: php, tinyurl

Quiero obtener varias URL acortadas de manera simultánea, el problema siguiente es que cuando las acorto, la primera URL si sale acortada correctamente, pero las demás se muestran así: `tinyurl.com/__urlqueacortas.url` y me da error ya que es una dirección errónea.

Aquí abajo pongo el código usado:

> Nota: `tinyurl . com` aparece separado, pero no es un error. Es porque el editor de Stack Overflow no me deja ponerlo junto si quiero publicar la pregunta.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" name="urls" cols="40"><?= $_POST['urls'] ?></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Acortar" class="btn-glow primary">
</form>

<?php

$enlace = $_POST['urls'];
$enlace2 = chop($enlace,'__');    // Elimina saltos de linea y espacio, pero solo al final de la cadena 
$enlace3 = nl2br($enlace2);         // Agregamos los saltos de linea <br /> 
$enlace4 = explode("<br />", $enlace3);    // Creamos array con los datos recibidos 

function acortar($link) {
    $enlace5 = file_get_contents('http://tinyurl . com/api-create.php?url='.$link.''.$key.'');
    return $enlace5;
}

foreach($enlace4 as $link){
    echo acortar($link);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien probé tu algoritmo y encontre el problema, pero vamos por parte:
Primero no hay necesidad de hacer este chop, ya te muestro en la version que te paso una mejor forma de hacerlo.

```
$enlace2 = chop($enlace,'__');
```

El problema esta que que aqui al agregar los 
 para saltos de lineas no estas reemplazando si no que estas agregando el salto de carro antes, y tampoco lo necesitas ya que el txt area te esta mandando los /n entonces para que intentarlos transformar

```
$enlace3 = nl2br($enlace2);
```

Luego por ultimo te recomiendo que pruebes esta api http://tiny-url.info/open_api.html hace un wrapper de todos los servicios de acortar y muestra mensajes de error cuando no puede acortarlo mas facil para manejar despues.

Te adjunto tu codigo corregido, agregue unos isset al post para poder probarlo y tambien deje la funcion que tu tenias y escribi acortar_api en la cual uso curl y la api ante mencionada.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" name="urls" cols="40"><?= isset($_POST['urls'])?$_POST['urls']:'' ?></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Acortar" class="btn-glow primary">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['urls'])){
$enlace = $_POST['urls'];
$enlace2 = str_replace(' ', '', $enlace);    // Elimina espacios blancos innecesarios pero no el salto de carro 
$enlace3 = explode("\n", $enlace2);    // Creamos array con los datos recibidos //FILTRANDO por el salto de carro que ya viene

foreach($enlace3 as $link){
    echo acortar_normal($link);
    echo "<br>";
}


}

function acortar_normal($link) {
    $key = "TUKEYAUI";
    $enlace5 = file_get_contents('http://tinyurl . com/api-create.php?url='.$link.''.$key.'');
    return $enlace5;
}

function acortar_api($link) {
    $key = "TUKEYAUI";
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    $post_data = array('format' => 'json',
                       'apikey' => $key,
                       'provider' => 'tinyurl_com',
                       'url' => $link );
    $api_url = 'http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    $resultado = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $resultado;

}
```

Pruebalo y me dices que tal.

Saludos!